# for loop in sequential form in R

Tags: r, for-loop, seq

I want to use the results of the sequential function as an input in the for loop in R, how can I do that? Please see the example below.

```
x1<-seq(1,100,10)

for (k in x1 ) {
L1<-
L2<- }
```

The  `L1`will be 1 and `L2` will be 11 for the first loop and `L1`will be 11 and `L2` will be 21 for the second loop. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the index of `x1` :

```
for (k in seq_along(x1[-1])) {
    L1<- x1[k]
    L2<- x1[k+1]
}
```

`seq_along` creates a sequence from `1:length(x1)`

```
seq_along(x1)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

We use `-1` because we want the loop to stop at the second last place as there is no `k + 1` for last value.